# Why does Image change position on browser size change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a image in html and when I change the size of the browser the image and text boxes also change their size and position. Can someone explain why this is so??

```
#economy123{
position:absolute;
top:67%;
left:53%;
}

<div class="result-temp"  >
<img id="economy123" src="{{ asset('assets/images/economy123.png') }}" >
</div>
```

Comment: Because you're using a percentage for it's placement.

Comment: It's simply because you use percentage instead of fixed pixel size..

Comment: From the code above, only the position should change (as it's a percentage), but there's no reference to size at all. If the size changes too, it must be defined somewhere as a percentage. If not, I'd love to see a demo.

Comment: By size I mean that when I reduce the size of the browser the image also changes its place like it goes up or down depending on the size change of the browser.. i may be writing wrong in english sorry for that

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle or similar with a sample? The code above is incomplete without knowing the style of `result-temp`. If `result-temp` has position absolute/relative and a defined width, the position of `economy123` should always be the same within it. What you describe could happen for numerous reasons: `result-temp` not having position defined, `result-temp` not having width defined, even maybe you want to use fixed position instead of absolute...

Answer (score 0):

If you want your image to stay on the same spot even after you resize your browser you need to use pixels instead of percentages.

For example:

```
.result-temp{
    width: 400px; 
    height: 400px;
}

#economy123{
    position:relative;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    width: 200px;  
    height: 200px; 
}

<div class="result-temp">
    <img id="economy123" src="{{ asset('assets/images/economy123.png') }}" >
</div>
```

This will keep the image centered even after the browser is resized.

Comment: using piel does make the image stay at the same place only when I change the size in up or down direction....when I change the browser size side ways then image changes position

Comment: What is piel? What does that mean?

Comment: Hmm that's wierd, that shouldn't happen if you have pixel width's and height's. Are you sure you gave `result-temp` a width and height as well using pixels? Can you provide a JSFiddle to see the code youre working with.